# « Là-haut » ou « en haut »

Tags: grammaire, sens, prépositions, locutions, dialectes

Les francophones m'ont appris à dire "il est là-haut" (dans le sens "il est à l'étage") plutôt que "il est en haut" - ce qu'avait suggéré ma scolarité en français. Je voudrais mieux comprendre la différence.

Spécifiquement :

- Y-a-t-il des situations où l'un est plus correct que l'autre (*là-haut*/*en haut*) ?
- S'agit-il de *parler lyonnais* ?

Comment: Pour dire "à l'étage" je dirais plutôt « en haut » parce que je n'ai pas besoin de désigner ,ou préciser, où ce trouve ce « haut », mais je pense que les deux se disent dans ce cas, et sans que ce soit un régionalisme, du moins « en haut » ne me choque pas et je le comprends sans problème. Mais les deux ne sont pas forcément interchangeables, si je montre du doigt quelque chose je dirais, par exemple  « ma maison est là-haut sur la colline ». Ceci dit, je pourrais aussi dire, « ma maison est là-haut, en haut de la colline  », « en haut » dans ce cas ne pouvant être remplacé par « là-haut ».

Comment: *là-haut* est un marquer déictique, *en haut* ne l'est pas. //"Elle se matérialise avec les déictiques de lieu tels que « ici » et « là »" https://semantique-gdr.fr/wiki/D%C3%A9ixis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pour *il est à l'étage* je dirais *il est au premier* ou  *il est en haut*.

De manière plus générale, ces expressions sont souvent interchangeables : *Il est arrivé en haut*, *il est arrivé là-haut*.

Voici quelques cas où l'une est plus indiquée que l'autre :

*Là-haut* :

- Plus courant si on le montre du doigt et d'une manière plus générale, si le lieu en question est visible (*up there*).
- La référence est plus souvent celle de l'observateur, on regarde plutôt vers le haut en le disant.

*En haut* :

- La référence est celle du lieu où se situe la personne ou l'objet en question.
- Peut être suivi d'une indication qui devient alors la référence (*En haut de la pile*), similaire à *upstairs*.
- S'accommode mieux du sens figuré (*La France d'en haut*)

Attention, le contraire d'*en haut* et *en bas* mais celui de *là-haut* n'est pas *là-bas*...